# SQL Server 2008 License for Full Text Search?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have a client which would like to use SQL 2008 FTS...but I was wondering is there a seperate license for it or when you buy a certain edition of SQL (which?) you get it included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope - not at all. FTS is built into Express editions (free) and upwards. The issue with licensing is [for other parts of the Sql Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx). Eg. Free edition only uses one Processor, has a DB size limit, etc.

For myself, I need to use as many processors as the machine has, so I can't use the free edition.

Comment: @Ardman : I've been here on SA for so long and i've never beaten anyone to a simple question! Yippie for me (for a change!) <- fail life.

Comment: But this also applies to commercial editions? ALL of them? Any limitations?

Comment: @Pure.Krome - SA? San Andreas? Social Anomaly? Sweaty Arse? :D

Comment: Correct. TFS for _ALL_ editions is FREE. It's the other issues -> Max #CPU's, DB size and Ram usage are the main differences between _any/all_ editions.

Comment: Are these limitations FTS specific or generally for that SQL Server (as the link you've pasted above)? Thnx for your help btw :)

Comment: @Vladan Strigo : These limitations are general SQL Server restrictions. So 1 CPU for the Express (free) edition applies to the entire Sql Server service that runs in the background. So any query's, etc (with or without FTS) will only take use of 1 CPU.